# Apache reverse proxy causing ~40 second delay on first access after idle

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have a simple Apache 2.2 reverse proxy setup on OSX with three virtual hosts all providing SSL and Open Directory authentication before forwarding everything to their respective back end servers.

For each of the three virtual hosts things work fine and seem fast enough, but if any of them is idle for more than 10 minutes or so (i don't have an accurate timing of this)from any given host, the first call takes almost a minute, then subsequent calls are <1s. This delay is definitely at the proxy, I see no traffic on the back end server until the last second of the wait.

What could I be doing wrong here? WHat can cause a reverse proxy to delay like this? Is it refreshing a cache? How do I go about debugging it?

My virtual hosts all look about the same and the rest of the apache config is bare bones, only the modules I need and very basic setup...

```
ServerRoot "/usr"
User _www
Group _www
DefaultType text/html

Listen 80
Listen 443
Listen 6660

DocumentRoot /Volumes/data/httpd

# Basic Requirements for a proxy
LoadModule mime_module libexec/apache2/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module libexec/apache2/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module libexec/apache2/mod_env.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so

# Needed for OD Authentication
LoadModule apple_auth_module libexec/apache2/mod_auth_apple.so

# Needed for SSL (duh)
LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log common

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLSessionCache shmcb:/var/run/ssl_scache(512000)
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
    SSLMutex file:/var/log/apache2/ssl_mutex
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl crl
</IfModule>


NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
NameVirtualHost *:6660


<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mysite.server.com

SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCipherSuite "ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM"
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLProxyProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/certificates/mysite.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/certificates/mysite.key"

<Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    AuthType Basic
    Require group <my access group>
    Allow from <my test ip>

    Satisfy Any
    AuthName "MyGroup"
</Location>

SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://backend.mysite.com/ retry=0 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse / http://backend.mysite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Additional info, if I fire off another request in quick succession, the second one completes in one second while the fist continues to wait

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you're having DNS resolution issues with `backend.mysite.com`, whatever the hostname really is. The DNS resolution is taking a long time, but once it's successful it gets cached for a few minutes. Once the cache expires, you are back to square one and get the wait again.

To resolve the issue, fix whichever DNS server is causing the problem, or use an IP address instead of the hostname.

Comment: My i can hit the backend server directly without any delay. It's all internal DNS and I have the same issues with all three virtual hosts. I will try direct to IP and see, but I am not sure that is the issue.

Comment: To bypass name resolution, use `hosts` file resolution. But, it could also be your apache config, if it's setup as worker. Try changing to prefork.